# How does the Athlete feat affect the Centaur playable race?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, movement, racial-traits, centaur

The Athlete feat (PHB, p. 165) has a point that says:

> climbing doesn't halve your speed.

The Centaur's Equine Build trait (GGtR, p. 16) says:

> any climb that uses both hands and feet is especially difficult for you because of your equine legs. When you make such a climb, each foot of movement costs you 4 extra feet, instead of the normal 1 extra foot.

The normal climb normally costs half your speed and athlete negates that, but the equine build costs you 80% of your speed instead of 50%.  How would these two interact with each other?

This question has nothing to do with the difference between listed climb speed and walking speed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a functional difference between having a listed climb speed and being able to climb at full walking speed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148385/is-there-a-functional-difference-between-having-a-listed-climb-speed-and-being-a)

Comment: Related (but not duplicate) question: [What is a Centaur Thief's climbing speed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/148558/39969)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## As of the 2018 Errata, the *Athlete* feat has been changed

> ***Athlete (p. 165).*** The third benefit should instead say climbing doesn't cost you extra movement.
>
> —[Errata: Player's Handbook](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf), 2018

Because of this change, the *Athlete* feat would allow a Centaur to ignore all extra costs associated with climbing. The technicality of ignoring "halved" movement speed is no longer relevant.

Comment: Hmm, that's a trick I'd really like to see in real life.

Comment: @DJClayworth check out mountain goats

Answer (score 1):

You become a mountain goat and essentially have the best climbing in the natural world.

> ***Athlete (p. 165).*** The third benefit should instead say climbing
>   doesn't cost you extra movement.
>   ~ [*2018 PHB Errata*](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. While you're right to point out the PHB errata, Xirema's existing answer already points this out (and explains the relevance a bit more)...